# Current directory in Azure DevOps yml

Tags: azure-pipelines

Is there a portable way of knowing the directory in which the current yml file exists in Azure DevOps. This would something equivalent of %~dp0 in dos batch files.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a portable way of knowing the directory in which the current yml file exists in Azure DevOps.

When you open the yml file in the Azure Devops, you will noticed that there is a path containing the file at the top of yml:

[image]

If you want to use scripts to get the path, you could use the [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1
```

In the return body, there is option `yamlFilename` with the path for the yml:

```
"process": {
    "yamlFilename": "/TestASP.NETProject/TestASP.NETProject/test2.yml",
    "type": 2
},
```

Then we could use powershell or batch to parse this path to get the directory of the  current yml file exists.

**Update:**

> I have two follow up qns: a) How can I setup a generic service
>   connection and b) how do I get the build definition id. Is it one of
>   the predefined variables in the pipeline?

First, we could use **PAT** to setup a generic service connection in the powershell task, like:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
   targetType : inline
   script: |
     $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1"
     $connectionToken="Your PAT Here"
     $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

     $buildPipeline= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get    

     $YamlFilename= $buildPipeline.process.yamlFilename

     Write-Host This is Build Result: $YamlFilename
```

Second, for the definition id, you could get it from the browser directly when you open/select your pipeline:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have two follow up qns: a) How can I setup a generic service connection and b) how do I get the build definition id. Is it one of the predefined variables in the pipeline?

Comment: @Chubsdad, update the answer, please check if it helps.

Comment: I could get it to work for my pipeline. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question with an answer, but just wanted to add that a really fast way to just get the current directory is using the command:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/(Add Desired folder here)/(Add Desired folder or file here)
```

Comment: This only works if the desired folder is known, because echo "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` is `/home/vsts/work/1/s`, even if the yaml file is in a subdirectory.